# terminal command to launch kde connect indicator

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-20.04, kde-plasma

What is the terminal command to launch kde-connect indicator on ubuntu 20.04?
Searched everywhere but couldn't find anything. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to launch it with `kdeconnect-indicator`.

In case that does not work, check if KDE Connect is correctly installed by running the KDE Connect CLI tool with `kdeconnect-cli --help`.